# Flow Complex Apex Defined

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow

I'm trying to pass an apex defined variable from LWC to flow, the class looks like this:

```
public class Subs {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String name{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<PhoneNumber> numbers{get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String iccid{get;set;}

    public Subs(String name, List<PhoneNumber> numbers, String iccid){
        this.name = name;
        this.numbers = numbers;
        this.iccid = iccid;
    }
```

}

it looks like that once I add the List PhoneNumber salesforce flow cant handle it since its another class.

I'm having the following error:
*The Lightning Component c:dataListPOC generated invalid output for field selectedSubs. Contact your administrator with these details: Flow encountered an error when processing and converting between data types. Please check the flow and ensure all data types are matched correctly.*

is this possible to pass this complex apex objects to flow or flow only allows primitive variables inside the object?

Than you

Answer (score 0):

So, Just understand why.

I dont know why but if PhoneNumber class has a constructor without params, it works.

```
public class PhoneNumber {
@AuraEnabled
public String country{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String numberX{get;set;}

public PhoneNumber(String country, String numberX){
    this.country = country;
    this.numberX = numberX;
}

public PhoneNumber(){

}
```

}